# Could trying to copy a file owned by another process cause a DirectoryNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, file, exception, io

The log I'm trying to work with belongs to another program that runs concurrently with my own. I get a DirectoryNotFoundException stating "Could not find a part of the path " when I try to make the copy. The assert does pass. The exception is thrown at File.Copy(...) itself. With the if(File.Exists(...)) in place, the program is clearly able to see the file before it attempts to copy it.

Edit: Could permissions be a possible cause? The directory is located in the root of the C drive.

Edit: By adding the two asserts suggested by Jim Mischel and stepping through in the cold light of a new day, newControlProgramLog path was revealed as the culprit. GetSaveFilePath() was returning a default path for the particular run state I was testing. I declared the default but never checked to see that it existed on program start up. The directory is now created if it does not exist, and the function now works as intended.

Shout out to Christian Hagelid for calling that it wasn't an issue with controlProgramLogPath from the start.

```
    private void CopyLogsToDataDirectoy()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(_controlProgramDirectory));

        string controlProgramLogPath = Path.Combine(_controlProgramDirectory, _controlProgramLogFileName);

        if (File.Exists(controlProgramLogPath))
        {
            string dataFilePath = GetSaveFilePath();
            string newControlProgramLogName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dataFilePath);
            newControlProgramLogName = newControlProgramLogName + ".control.log";

            string newControlProgramLogPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dataFilePath);
            newControlProgramLogPath = Path.Combine(newControlProgramLogPath, newControlProgramLogName);

            File.Copy(controlProgramLogPath, newControlProgramLogPath);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that `newControlProgramLogPath` is unique? If you don't pass in the optional boolean parameter you will get an exception if you try to save it to a file that already exists

Comment: @ChristianHagelid: The exception you get in that case is `IOException`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

`DirectoryNotFoundException` occurs when part of the path you specified does not exist. It does not occur because a file is locked. If you get `DirectoryNotFoundException`, then it's almost certainly because the string you supplied does not reference a valid directory path. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directorynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx) also says that you can get this exception if your code doesn't have the `PathDiscovery` permission. I suspect that's pretty unlikely in your case.

You should check the paths in `controlProgramLogPath` and `newControlProgramLogPath` immediately before calling `File.Copy`.

```
Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(controlProgramLogPath));
Debug.Assert(Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newControlProgramLogPath));
```

I suspect that will reveal the problem.